# Centering Modal, or div when positioned

Tags: css, popup, modal-dialog

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juanpastas/bBvCK/3), how can I center the blue div without fixed width and height in the parent and child?

This is to post in SO

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```

## Update

These are positioned elements, I want child at the center of the screen.

## Update 2

See it centered [here](http://jsfiddle.net/juanpastas/bBvCK/6/), but I can't use fixed widths nor heights in parent neither children. I need positioned elements because I need them to be over other elements.

Comment: I don't know if i understand your problem, but I think <center></center> in HTML centers the element at the center, why don't you use it..

Comment: <center> is a depreciated tag @sna2stha

Comment: instead of <center> for centering element you can use align="center". <div class="child" align="center"></div>

Comment: Anyway I don't have problem aligning horizontally, but that's a good idea. My problem is vertically

Comment: you can use  <div class="child" valign="center;"></div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To center a div, you simply have to add this attribute:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

or a more condensed version (assuming 0px for the top and bottom margin):

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

This assumes that you have some sort of width value on that element you want to center, whether fixed or a percentage.  You shouldn't need anything in the parent to dictate the child's margins.

Comment: I need the fixed element, because I need a centered modal, margin auto does not work

Comment: So what of your source code and CSS is strictly off limits and has to remain what it is?  If you're trying to vertically and horizontally center a box in a parent element, I'd go about it much differently than you've got in your Fiddle.

Comment: See it centered here http://jsfiddle.net/juanpastas/bBvCK/6/, but I can't use fixed widths nor heights in parent neither children. I need positioned elements because I need them to be over other elements

Comment: So are you doing an overlay, such as a semi-translucent layer over the entire body/document?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/designbymichael/cujDt/1/  It uses a little jQuery and some CSS to dynamically position your box and the overlay.  I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do or not, but maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

> margin-top: -50%; /* why this takes the width of the parent ???? */

It's because your parent div has `position: fixed` and your child div has `position: absolute` and since absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.

So your child div will take a margin top and margin left with a value equal to `-50%` of your parent width which is `-50% * 150 = 75px`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's display in center of width.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.parent{
}
.child{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightblue;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your problem, but this needs [JQuery[.width()]](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

```
.parent{
    position: fixed;    
    /* I can't use static width nor height, TO DELETE(try changing this)*/
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;    
}

.child{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; 
    /*Simulate width and height, these are actually calculated by content*/
    width: 100px;
    height:50px;
    background: lightblue;   
}
```

JQuery onLoad:[**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/bBvCK/11/)**]

```
$(function changePostion() {
    var s = $(".parent").width(); 
    var e = $(".child").width();   
    var d= (s-e)/2;
    $(".child").css({"left":d}); 
    var sh = $(".parent").height(); 
    var eh = $(".child").height(); 
    var dh= (sh-eh)/2;
    $(".child").css({"top":dh});    
});
```

This [**article**](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/) is a best tutorial for positioning html attribute in center.  There might be a better way to do without using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic modals can be the biggest pains in the world. You need JS to change the heights and widths. Can you use a plugin? If so here are some good options. Twitter bootstrap has a modal that's very easy to get set up but it's challenging to load divs via ajax and iframes. You have to choose one or the other. simplemodal (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) is good but you still need to do a lot of the work yourself. It works with iframes and ajax content.